# How do I generate a random FRIEND CODE that can only be used once?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm creating an Android app, where I'd like to have a 'BUY 1 - send 1 to your friend' option.

I've been testing the idea of having a FREE limited version of my android app on the store and once a user has purchased the app they receive a FRIEND CODE that can be given to a chum to input into the FREE limited version, which ublocks the full version.

My concern is that 1 FRIEND CODE will be used multiple times - How do i make sure that after I've generated a friend code it can only be used once?

Any idea will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create a list of used codes saved into your db table some where and check it if it already used. I would have suggested check for already generated but I am guess you probably have the code ready not to produce duplicate random friend codes.

Comment: how can i check if the code is all ready used in another device?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing Krishna's suggestion... When that code is used it is put up into the DB, and then whenever one attempts to use a code, that DB is checked to see if that code is already listed and thus already used.

Comment: the DB must be in a server so all device can check if the code has been used or not? Is that your idea?

Comment: that's my and Tam's idea. Hope it helps.